# How to fetch select option text inside another input in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, onchange, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formgroups

I have a select field in my Angular Reactive Form and i want to pull the value of text inside the `<option>` tag which the user selects and then dynamically fill its value in the input (like on change event)

**COMPONENT.HTML**

```
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Select Plant</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="plantId" name="plantId" id="plantId">
                          <option [ngValue]="1">ABC</option>
                          <option [ngValue]="2">XYZ</option>  
                        </select>
                        <app-control-messages [control]="storlocForm.get('plantId')"></app-control-messages>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Plant Name *</label>
                        <input id="plantName" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="plantName" name="plantName" value="" />
                    </div>
```

Suppose if the user selects XYZ from the dropdown i want the value "XYZ" to be filled in the following input (plantName) not the value "2".

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
this.storlocForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      plantId: ['', Validators.required],
      plantName: ['']
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the change event to the select element and update the formcontrol like below.

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="plantId" name="plantId" id="plantId" (change)="update($event)">
                 <option [ngValue]="1">ABC</option>
                          <option [ngValue]="2">XYZ</option>  
                </select>

update(event): void {
        let plantName = event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
        this.form.controls.plantName.setValue(plantName);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must be using key value pair for the array so user  {key : "XYZ", value: "XYZ"},{key:"ABC", value: "ABC"}

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: I mean you can use key value pair same  if you dont want to fetch though dropdown